# App crashing due to ASIHTTP framework

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am developing an iPhone application that is using ASIHTTP framework for rest web services. Somehow my application is crashing and am getting error like below

```
Application(1565,0x3b06318c) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=32768) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

and the crash was occurring in the following code from ASIHTTPRequest class

```
    CFRunLoopSourceContext context = {0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    CFRunLoopSourceRef source = CFRunLoopSourceCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &context);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), source, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    BOOL runAlways = YES; // Introduced to cheat Static Analyzer
    while (runAlways) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 1.0e10, true);
        [pool drain];
    }

    // Should never be called, but anyway
    CFRunLoopRemoveSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), source, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    CFRelease(source);
```

I Googled about this crash, and I read that it's a problem with a `memory allocator` and didn't get much information. Also, I analyzed and don't have any potential leaks. My application is ready to be submitted to the App Store also. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

I found where the crash was happend. When the Other Process becomes to Zero KB In the Utilization Comparison then my application was crashing in the             `CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 1.0e10, true);` line.

[image]

Comment: is it synchronous call or async?

Comment: It's a synchronous call.

Comment: try async calls, i also had problem with synchronous calls.. it crashes randomly for no reason, but with async calls its working fine.

Comment: ASIHTTP framework is no longer supported by it's developer.
it would be far easier to switch to AFNetworking 2.0.
http://afnetworking.com/

Comment: @Raz, thanks for your replay. Noe I con't move to AFNetworking as it's   ready to be Apple Store.

Comment: I updated my question, please have a look on it.

Comment: seems yyou are using way too much memory

Comment: and then malloc can't give you the memory you want

Comment: are you downloading huge file(s) in memory?

Comment: @G.Ganesh, even though you are submitting your app to the app store, i honestly believe that the app would be better of not using unsupported libraries or frameworks. When trying to fix old code, and especially code that is not your own, you may find yourself wasting too many hours on debugging... hours that could be invested in changing the framework.
By the Way, maybe, in your future apps, you should consider warping these sort of libraries in your own "NetworkManager" or something, so that your code would not be depended on outsourced libraries.

Comment: @Daij-Djan, I'm not downloading any files. Am calling around 40 web services in all views in my app.

Comment: @Raz, I will shift to AFNetworking but will it resolve my problem?

Comment: @Raz, CocoaPods is really required if I use AFNetworking?

Comment: @G.Ganesh, it should. besides, there is a rich and supporting community for AFNetworking, so that the chances are that if you will encounter any problems, you will receive much more support.
I personally now days use Apple's existing network classes (for educational reasons), but on all of my latest projects i have used AFNetworking, which made my life much more easy :)
As well, i guess that a "live" framework does not have any malloc warnings / problems which are not being handled.

Comment: @G.Ganesh,no. all you need is to add to your project's library the AFNetworking files.
you can pull them from git hub: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
then #import them where you need.
i recommend to create a ServerManager class, that will wrap AFNetworking, so that if you will feel like switching the library, or maybe create something on your own, it won't be a problem, and the code that was implemented in your view controllers would not need any changes.

Comment: @Raz, How to create a ServerManager class and how it will wrap AFNetworking? Can you please provide some more information.

Comment: @Raz, I implemented something like below but it's not returning any status code(200) like in ASIHTTPRequest. Am I using wrong?       AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@ ",responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43879/discussion-between-g-ganesh-and-raz)

Comment: @G.Ganesh, if you are inside the success block, then you did receive status 200. the response you are NSLoging is suppose to be the JSON object you are getting back.